# Is there possible to create widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have built a Keyboard in Flutter, and I need to convert it into a Widget is it possible to convert that app into a widget in Flutter?

I want to build a widget for the Keyboard in Flutter for Both Android and IOS with the same code is it possible if it is possible kindly let me know.

Comment: I'm not clear if "Widget" in this context is a flutter widget, or a recently introduced ios and android "widget" that can appear in various positions for easy access.  I think you can build ios widgets using dart technology according to some recent publications I saw.

Answer (score 1):

Custom widgets are the building blocks of a Flutter application. They allow developers to create reusable UI components that can be used throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this for later purposes as a readymade widget, you can create a package. How to create a package, you can follow [this](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-packages)